# Blank Text Message from random number - is it a virus?

Tags: sms, antivirus

So I just got a blank text message from some number that I don't know. My worry is that this is some sort of intrusion attempt.

My understanding is whenever I receive a text message, or a message with media, my phone automatically downloads it. So me receiving a blank text message from some unknown number leads me to believe that there was some sort of virus attached to the message and when the phone downloads the message, it will download that virus automatically.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible that this is a virus?
- How can I check to see if my phone has a virus?
- Is there a way to detect an intrusion attempt so that my phone will tell me if something is happening that shouldn't be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that this is a virus?

Of course it is *possible*. Technology is beat. But what actually matters is whether if it is *probable* or not.

A text message (if it is an SMS) has to travel through the cellular network of your service provider and therefore the file types you can send are object to their limitations. Such messages can include media files(MMS) but not apps or executables. Instead, it might contain a link which'll lead you to download a malware. But an empty SMS on its own to infect a phone, sounds pretty NSA.

> How can I check to see if my phone has a virus?

You can use antivirus apps but their reliability is up for discussion.

> Is there a way to detect an intrusion attempt so that my phone will tell me if something is happening that shouldn't be?

Again, some antivirus apps like Avast warn you whenever an app that is malicious is being installed. But there are ways to outsmart it too.

Nonetheless, for your specific case, relax. I really don't think you are at risk.